# Obtener valores de ngModel

Tags: angular, primeng

Tengo en mi .ts

```
fxs: any[] = [];
let currencies = [{name:'EUR'}, {name:'USD'}, {name:'SOL'}]
```

y en mi .html

```
<div> {{fxs}} </div>
<p-table [value]="currencies" responsiveLayout="scroll">
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Fx</th>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-curren let-ri="rowIndex">
          <tr>
              <td>{{ri}}{{curren.name}}</td>
              <td>
                <input [(ngModel)]="fxs[ri].name" name="{{curren.name}}" value="{{curren.currency.name}}" type="text" pInputText>
                <p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="fxs[ri].fx" name="{{curren[ri]}}"></p-inputNumber> 
              </td>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

pero en mi .html, lo que necesito saber es el usuario que valores ha dado a ese currency y se guarden en la variable fxs

```
{{fxs}}   => no me muestra nada
```

Aclaraciones

```
ri> es el index del array
```

Me gustaria tener algo asi en la variable fxs, el valor de fx depende lo que ponga el usuario en el inputnumber

```
[{name:'EUR', fx:1}, {name:'USD', fx:2}, {name:'SOL', fx:3}]
```

Comment: Hola @sirdaiz. No consigo entender tu pregunta. Por un lado dices que {{fxs}} no se muestra, pero es que ni siquiera está en tu plantilla, luego es normal que no se muestre. Por otro lado, dices que tienes definido fxs como any, pero ¿no está inicializado?. Si no tiene valores (aunque sean vacíos), no podrás acceder a ellos. Tampoco se qué es **ri**, de dónde viene, qué valor tiene. Creo que hace falta algo más de información. Si pudieras poner algo más de código sería de ayuda.

Comment: @PedroGonzález he modificado mi post con las dudas que me preguntas

Comment: Trabajar con vectores en la plantilla es complicado porque si tu vector fxs está vacío, cualquier valor de ri dará un error. Para mi es muy difícil evaluar el error sin ver el código en el componente, ya que no se si fxs[ri] tiene algún valor, ni qué campos contiene ni nada. Deberías incluir el código de tu .ts o al menos aquel que sea relevante para la pregunta. Por otro lado, Angular no te va a renderizar en la vista un vector de objetos, así que si {{fxs}} es sólo para depuración, es mejor que lo saques a consola con **console.log(fxs)**

Comment: he añadido más informacion y lo que me gustaria

Comment: De lo que has puesto deduzco que donde dice **[(ngModel)]="fxs[ri].fxs"** debería decir **[(ngModel)]="fxs[ri].fx"**, pero no puedo sacar nada más. Como te digo, si no pones el código no puedo saber qué valores llegan en el vector **fxs** ni qué valores toma *ri**. Sospecho que estás pasando un elemento del vector que no tiene valor, pero sin ver el código no te puedo decir dónde está el fallo exactamente.

Comment: Si es "fxs[ri].fx". no hay más código, lo que hago es reocrrer la variable currencies para que el usuario ponga los valores a cada currency, el RI es solo pruebas, podemos prescindir de él, miestras en una variable pueda tener algo así [{name:'EUR', fx:1}, {name:'USD', fx:2}, {name:'SOL', fx:3}]

Comment: ya lo solucioens haciendo esto:     for (let x=0; x<this.currencies.length; x++) {
      console.log(x)
      this.fxs[x] = new Object();
    }

Comment: Correcto. Eso es lo que te decía, que el vector no tenía valor, no estaba inicializado y estabas llamando a un objeto que no existía. Con el for lo que has hecho es crear esos objetos. Pero sin ver tu código no podía asegurarlo ni sugerirte cómo hacerlo. Me alegro de que hayas encontrado tú la solución porque pienso que se aprende más cuando lo encuentras tú mismo que cuando te dan la solución hecha.